# How to change post cpt with submit button?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, posts

Εvery post must have an submit button and when user click it then the post goes to another cpt.

```
function click_button()
{
 $button=  '<form id="formid" action="button.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="button" class="button"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button"/>
</form>';
    
    return $button;
}

add_shortcode( 'button', 'click_button' );
```

```
button.php

function button()
    {
    
    if($_POST['submit']) {
    
        //echo "Hello world!";
         $data = array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_type' => 'bdg_books_wanted'
       );

        wp_update_post( $data );
        
}
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: you shouldn't make direct calls to PHP files in your plugin/theme from forms or javascript on your site like that, it's a security risk and results in code that breaks regularly. It also means your PHP files are forced into a very specific place because you're forced to load WordPress manually so that functions such as `wp_update_post` work

Comment: Instead make the request to the same URL with an empty `action` attribute, and use hidden inputs to detect when the form has been submitted